# Call and embed a Yammer feed without authenticating the user?

Tags: c#, oauth, yammer

I've configured an app in Yammer, have the Key And Secret values and all that stuff. What I'd like to do is get a feed of messages without authenticating the user.  Is this possible and, if so, are there any samples available?  Right now I'm using c# and  Yammer.Oss.Api.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a service account then generate an access token with the user. There's a sample code here - http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2015/02/24/consuming-yammer-restful-api-with-angularjs-for-dummies.aspx